# Palo Alto monitor bandwidth usage using SNMP

Tags: firewall, snmp, palo-alto

I'm trying to monitor bandwidth usage on my Palo Alto firewall using SNMP. However only the ifInOctets & ifOutOctets counters of VLAN interfaces are updated. The counters for real interfaces are all 0. Is there something I need to turn on?

Edit: Palo Alto 3020

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that it isn't possible to monitor bandwidth on this specific device by browsing through the MIB. I'm now monitoring bandwidth with Netflow.

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

We are monitoring Palo Alto 3020 with Solarwind NPM and able to get in BW usage logs for both VLAN & physical interface. 
You can refer the below link for detail config
https://knowledgebase.paloaltonetworks.com/KCSArticleDetail?id=kA10g000000ClHaCAK